# How to install Omega T (Cat Tools) and JRE on Loki

Tags: software-installation

I need precise tutorial about installing Omega T (Cat Tools for translation) on Loki. In this case, Omega T need JRE and I have not installed the JRE yet. Is anybody here can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to their site, you should download the version including JRE:
[Omega T + JRE for Linux x64 Direct Link](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/omegat/OmegaT%20-%20Latest/OmegaT%204.1.1/OmegaT_4.1.1_Beta_Linux_64.tar.bz2?r=&ts=1493491348&use_mirror=netcologne)

Unpack the downloaded archive, right-click the newly created OmegaT_4.1.1_Beta_Linux_64 folder -> Open in -> Terminal. In here, input `./linux-install.sh` and press Enter.
From Terminal, launch it with `omegat` command. This should be it.

There is also an omegat version available in the ubuntu repository, but that is aparently not working properly. This one installs with `sudo apt install omegat` , but I got a  `Suitable java binary not found` error, even though I am sure I have it installed

EDIT: the version from their own website is 4.1, so yeah, the repository version, at 2.3 relesed in 2013, is terribly outdated